# Get activity from ActivityManager

Tags: android

How to get activity from ActivityManager and show it? I mean, for example, we open another activity via intent and I want show it again in the same state, as it was. This activity has WebView with comlicated JS, that's why I cannot use opening again with Bundle.

Comment: If by "closed" you mean "destroyed", as dhams notes, there is no way to get that back. If by "closed" you mean something else, please explain in greater detail.

Comment: No, I mean we just away from activity to another via intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get activity from ActivityManager and show it?

You don't. `ActivityManager`, despite its name, has little to do with activities. Here, "Activity" refers to the general English noun, not the Android component.

> I mean, for example, we open another activity via intent and I want show it again in the same state, as it was

Call `startActivity()` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` as a flag and an `Intent` identifying your activity. If your activity exists in your task, it will be brought back to the foreground. If your activity does not exist in your task, it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

If that `Activity` has removed from activity stack then there are no way get it back.

Comment: No, I mean we just away from activity to another via intent.